# How do I dynamically invoke methods in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, invoke, dynamicmethod

At runtime I'm grabbing a list of method names on a class, and I want to invoke these methods.  I understand how to get the first part done from here:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/JN3535-Reflection

```
GroovyObject.methods.each{ println it.name }
```

What I can't seem to find information on is how to then invoke a method once I've grabbed its name.

What I want is to get here:

```
GroovyObject.methods.each{ GroovyObject.invokeMethod( it.name, argList) }
```

I can't seem to find the correct syntax.  The above seems to assume I've overloaded the default invokeMethod for the GroovyObject class, which is NOT the direction I want to go.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Groovy allows for dynamic method invocation as well as dynamic arguments using the spread operator:

```
def dynamicArgs = [1,2]
def groovy = new GroovyObject()
GroovyObject.methods.each{ 
     groovy."$it.name"(staticArg, *dynamicArgs)
}
```

Reference [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140206164914/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy)

Question answered [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140206164914/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The provided link is dead.  Does this link similar?
http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_dynamic_method_names

Comment: I updated the link to point to an archived version of the original, now dead link.  Happy metaprogramming!

Answer (score 23):

Once you get a `MetaMethod` object from the metaclass, you can call `invoke` on it.  For example:

```
class MyClass {
    def myField = 'foo'
    def myMethod(myArg) { println "$myField $myArg" }
}
test = new MyClass()
test.metaClass.methods.each { method ->
    if (method.name == 'myMethod') {
        method.invoke(test, 'bar')
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the name directly:

```
methodName = 'myMethod'
test."$methodName"('bar')
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the method exists without iterating over `metaClass.methods`?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel The [`respondsTo()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#respondsTo(java.lang.String)) method will tell you if the method exists.  Example: `if (test.respondsTo(methodName)) { ... }`